# Backbone JS error on Kanban boards with XRay Jira plugin installed

Tags: jira, jira-xray

While evaluating upgraded Jira Server instance (from 7.10 to 9.6) while using Kanban board the following Javascript error occurs which was not present in the 7.10 version:

```
Details
Exception: Uncaught Error: raven/autocomplete/model missing backbone
Resource: http://localhost:8080/s/b855e4b61aa53162eb40093bda935693-CDN/-2qx7vv/970000/1dlckms/b87f44793d8513094809e29427bfab81/_/download/contextbatch/js/_super,-com.atlassian.plugins.atlassian-plugins-webresource-rest:data-collector-perf-observer,-jira.webresources:resource-phase-checkpoint-init/batch.js?locale=en-UK
Line: 10
Column: 1967
Environment
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/111.0.1661.54
Stack trace
Error: raven/autocomplete/model missing backbone
at l (http://localhost:8080/s/b855e4b61aa53162eb40093bda935693-CDN/-2qx7vv/970000/1dlckms/b87f44793d8513094809e29427bfab81/_/download/contextbatch/js/_super,-com.atlassian.plugins.atlassian-plugins-webresource-rest:data-collector-perf-observer,-jira.webresources:resource-phase-checkpoint-init/batch.js?locale=en-UK:10:1973)
at u (http://localhost:8080/s/b855e4b61aa53162eb40093bda935693-CDN/-2qx7vv/970000/1dlckms/b87f44793d8513094809e29427bfab81/_/download/contextbatch/js/_super,-com.atlassian.plugins.atlassian-plugins-webresource-rest:data-collector-perf-observer,-jira.webresources:resource-phase-checkpoint-init/batch.js?locale=en-UK:10:946)
at l (http://localhost:8080/s/b855e4b61aa53162eb40093bda935693-CDN/-2qx7vv/970000/1dlckms/b87f44793d8513094809e29427bfab81/_/download/contextbatch/js/_super,-com.atlassian.plugins.atlassian-plugins-webresource-rest:data-collector-perf-observer,-jira.webresources:resource-phase-checkpoint-init/batch.js?locale=en-UK:10:1949)
at u (http://localhost:8080/s/b855e4b61aa53162eb40093bda935693-CDN/-2qx7vv/970000/1dlckms/b87f44793d8513094809e29427bfab81/_/download/contextbatch/js/_super,-com.atlassian.plugins.atlassian-plugins-webresource-rest:data-collector-perf-observer,-jira.webresources:resource-phase-checkpoint-init/batch.js?locale=en-UK:10:946)
at l (http://localhost:8080/s/b855e4b61aa53162eb40093bda935693-CDN/-2qx7vv/970000/1dlckms/b87f44793d8513094809e29427bfab81/_/download/contextbatch/js/_super,-com.atlassian.plugins.atlassian-plugins-webresource-rest:data-collector-perf-observer,-jira.webresources:resource-phase-checkpoint-init/batch.js?locale=en-UK:10:1949)
at http://localhost:8080/s/b855e4b61aa53162eb40093bda935693-CDN/-2qx7vv/970000/1dlckms/b87f44793d8513094809e29427bfab81/_/download/contextbatch/js/_super,-com.atlassian.plugins.atlassian-plugins-webresource-rest:data-collector-perf-observer,-jira.webresources:resource-phase-checkpoint-init/batch.js?locale=en-UK:10:2469
```

While it doesn't break any features in the Kanban board itself, it would be prefered the error wouldn't occur.

Managed to reproduce the error even on a new Jira installation on Docker version 9.4.1 with the following plugins installed:

- Adaptavist ScriptRunner for JIRA (latest)
- Automation for Jira (latest)
- JSU Automation Suite for Jira Workflows (latest)
- WorklogPRO (latest)
- XRay (6.4.1-j9)

Steps to reproduce the issue:

- Create a Docker volume (ie. jira-vol1)
- Run Jira in Docker: docker run -v jira-vol1:/var/atlassian/application-data/jira --name=jira-local -d -p 8080:8080 Atlassian/jira-software
- Setup the instance and install all plugins
- Create a Kanban Sample project
- Open the created Kanban Board
- Drag & Drop any issue to any other swimlane

Comment: Thanks for providing all that context. I would recommend you to reach out Xray support team (https://jira.getxray.app/servicedesk/customer/portal/2) and report it, providing all the necessary logs so the development team can analyze it. There's not much we can do from here.

Comment: Thank you Sérgio, submitted a new ticket.